# Changing timeout time in Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

how can I change timeout interval time to get long running API response in Alamofire.

I have tried with following code:

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 300.0 // seconds    
let alamofireManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)

alamofireManager.request(method, urlString, parameters: parameters)
        .authenticate(user: primaryUserName, password: primaryPassword)
        .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
        .responseJSON {

            alamofireResponse in

            if alamofireResponse.response == nil {

               print("nil response")
            }
}
```

But it is not getting any data. Response is nil. what can be done now? Thanks.

Comment: were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create your own session configuration with your 3 second timeout, then create a custom Manager instance. More info can be found in the [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#modifying-session-configuration).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have done that above right?

Comment: This answer is not correct – you're already using a customer `SessionManager` with a modified timeout value.